# Can 'vector' be used in yylval of yacc?

Tags: bison, yacc

I want to define `yylval` as follows:

```
%union {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
    struct s_con {
        char exp[30];
        vector<Where*> v_wheres;   
    } *p_s_con;
}
```

Here `Where` is a class.
Then I find an error in y.tab.h:
`'vector’ does not name a type`

Comment: Are you compiling as a c++ parser?  Did you include, in the preamble, whatever header defines `vector`?

Comment: I use command yacc -d yacc.y to get y.tab.c and y.tab.h. Then I find all header defines are in y.tab.c, not in y.tab.h.

Comment: Ok.  At the top of the bison file, inside the `%{...%}` block, did you put `#include <vector>`?

Comment: The header defines '#include <vector>' is in y.tab.c, not in y.tab.h. Maybe I can manually add '#include <vector>' into y.tab.h?

Comment: @slimpig: Does adding `std::` like `std::vector<Where*>` solve the error?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `std::vector` in the Bison parser stack, since it is not a so called POD (plain old data type, which are integers, floats, old structures, unions and pointers) object. This is a C++ limitation.

Comment: Note that C++11 allows non-POD types in unions, but making them work will require support from bison in the skeleton

Answer (score 2):

In Section 10.1.2 *'C++ Semantic Values'* of the Bison (2.4.3) manual, you can find:

> The `%union` directive works as for C, see Section 3.7.4 [The Collection of Value Types],
>   page 66. In particular it produces a genuine `union`<sup>1</sup>, which have a few specific features in
>   C++.
>
> - The type `YYSTYPE` is defined but its use is discouraged: rather you should refer to the
>     parser’s encapsulated type yy::parser::semantic_type.
> - Non POD (Plain Old Data) types cannot be used. C++ forbids any instance of classes
>     with constructors in unions: only pointers to such objects are allowed.
>     Because objects have to be stored via pointers, memory is not reclaimed automatically:
>     using the `%destructor` directive is the only means to avoid leaks. See Section 3.7.7 [Freeing
>     Discarded Symbols], page 68.
>
> <sup>1</sup> In the future techniques to allow complex types within pseudo-unions (similar to Boost variants) might
>   be implemented to alleviate these issues.

So, you could perhaps use a pointer to a vector of `Where` pointers, but you'd have to supply the appropriate destructor.